# dijit embedded BorderContainer does not work inside template

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I have an embedded BorderContainer that works fine when the markup is within the main page. When I move the border container markup inside a widget with template, something goes wrong and the border container position all its children on top left corner on top of each other.

Here is a minimalistic snippet that shows the problem:
http://embed.plnkr.co/cngYmG6BMKcUxwKQy2Du/

The same thing happens when I run locally with dojo version 1.12.1

Please can you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: there is a height problem , that I think it's caused by widget declarative instantiation .  have you tried a programative instantiation ?

Comment: No I have not tried programative instantiation. I just found out a hack as a workaround; calling resize() on the embedded BorderContainer inside setTimeout : https://embed.plnkr.co/VNDsd7iT82IqdIFQbaxy/ . But I would rather not rely on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of [dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html)...

> The dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin mixin does not support adding layout widgets as children. In particular there are issues with startup() and resize() calls to the children.

Comment: Is there another way in Dojo/Dijit to split the markup into smaller files, that can contain layout widgets?

Comment: Nothing supported to my knowledge.  Even with bRIMOs solution, you may have 'resize' event issues down the line - which can be overcome with ugly window onresize handlers.  Ideally you either have to (a) have all your layouts decoratively placed up front, or (b) substitute layouts in your widgets to standard 'responsive' design.

Comment: @LewisM yep, but the programmatic doesn't need the resize event ! it's rendered correctly , doesn't it ?

Comment: Thanks Lewis. As for a), is not really applicable in my case and for b) what is appealing for me in dojo/dijit are the widgets, as I am trying to emulate a desktop application

Answer (score 1):

You can get this to work, but you have to forward the resize requests to the BorderContainer on your own.

One rule to keep in mind is that Dojo layout widgets will call resize if they have a single child widget. If there are multiple widgets it doesn't know how much space to give to each one, throws its hands up and its up to you to figure out the sizing.

Give the BorderContainer in your template an attach point name with `data-dojo-attachpoint="bc"`. Then overload the resize method and forward the resize request.

```js
isLayoutContainer: true,

resize: function(changeSize, resultSize) {
    this.inherited(arguments);        
    this.bc.resize(changeSize, resultSize);
}
```

This assumes the BorderContainer is the only thing worthy of sizing, i.e. takes up all of the space for your widget.

Since you are now calling resize on your children, you are acting like a layout widget, so you should also define `isLayoutContainer` as shown. The resize API isn't well documented, and isLayoutContainer even less so.  Without it you might notice extraneous resize calls when your window size changes.

If you later create content above or below the border container, you'll need to adjust changeSize.w and changeSize.h accordingly. And this gets harder on a call like `myWidget.resize()` where changeSize and resultSize are not provided, and you have to use the current size or otherwise figure it out. [dojo/dom-geometry](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.10/dojo/dom-geometry.html) is helpful in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As lewis Mentioned this does not support Layout widget as children ,
What I suggest to you , is using the programmatic approach by instantiating the widget inside the main script as bellow :

```
require(["dojo/_base/array", 
         'dojo/_base/declare',
         "dojo/parser", 
         "dojo/on", 
         "myapp/MyWidget", 
         "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
         "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
         'dojo/domReady!'], 
         function(array, declare, parser, on, MyWidget) {
            console.log("b4 parse ....") 
            parser.parse().then(function() {
                console.log("after parse ...."); 

                //create your widget here  
                new MyWidget({}).placeAt("borderContainer3"); 

            }); 
         }
);
```

You can find here a customized [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/jusofSX6MjVieZhPDD2I/).

Comment: Thanks bRIMOs for your suggestion, Layout does work fine, but when I add additional stuff inside the contentPanes I have other problems with the template, I guess related to the lifecycle